# Google Cloud - Signup Error OR_BACR_234, OR_CBAT_15, etc. - ANY Known Fixes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been attempting to set up a GCP account for two weeks.

The first, and most prevalent error: [OR_BACR_234] doesn't come with any explanation. Support doesn't have one; I can't find one. I've gone through Google's Issue Tracker and found a bunch of complaints dated from 02/23 and on, but no resolutions.

The second error I've gotten is: [OR_CBAT_15] and this also comes with zero indication of any issue or solution. However, my cards are billed the temporary amount held by Google when this error is thrown. So, the cards are billed and I still have no account access.

I've also been getting "You'll need to contact support to finish setting up your account." which leads me to a support link - a deadloop support link as I can't access the support w/o the Billing Account set up.

Does anyone have any idea what this is? Does anyone have a reliable fix? Does anyone have any f'ing idea what we can do to address it? I've found hundreds of people in the last few months with the same issue and no one posted solutions. I've posted a GCP Forum - Cloud Hub; Opened a new live Issue Tracker ticket; have an ongoing support ticket open with two Google teams.

I'd normally just jump to another cloud provider but I've kind of built the entire infrastructure around GCP - GPU/TPU access, hosting MongoDB/RESTful API, BigQuery access, Stackdriver logs/monitoring, and most importantly the Docker to Kubernetes pipeline. I realize I can piece this together somewhere else, but Google's VertexAI, Keras, native K8s, etc. make it a really good place to work. Also, the $400 free-trial credit for business emails was SUPER helpful for me.

I know this isn't a typical Stack question. I just don't know what the hell else I'm supposed to do. Ideas? Experience? Thoughts? Anything at all that could help?

I've tried three different billing profiles, two different cards, ten different connections - w/ VPN and w/o. I've been passed from support agent to support agent with zero help. The support agents keep recommending I talk to GCP Billing Support, but it's a deadloop because you can't actually do so without an active Billing Account - which is what I'm trying to set up in the first place.

For context: I've tried the Incognito window; cleared my cookies/cache; etc. Anything like that I've already done.

I've created new connections; used Incognito; logged into a new Google account; created new billing profiles; connected debit cards/bank accounts. I've done all of this multiple ways and in multiple variations.

Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it. I'm falling way behind waiting for this to get resolved.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured this out. I wanted to post an answer in case anyone else was in a similar situation.

The only way this issue is solved is via support, and because you're unable to contact the Billing Account support you've got to go on a real journey.

- Contact GCP Support and explain the issue. They're going to send you a specific form to fill out, and it will get passed to the GCP Billing Support team.
- This might take time and several messages back and forth - don't give up; be concise and explicit in your responses. You will eventually get the correct form. Fill it out and send it back. Be sure to use the email that's going to be controlling the GCP Billing Account.
- Be detailed in your message to GCP Billing Support. They will go back and forth with you for a few days, but eventually, they will "Green Light" your account. This only lasts for 24-48 hours, max. I waited three days, accidentally missing the reply from the GCP Billing team, and they needed to do it again. This is where you'll finally sign up and create the Billing Account.
- They'll then ask you to verify the card or bank account belongs to you by depositing a few pence into your bank account. Verify that transaction immediately or it's all got to start again. Once this is done... you're in.

**TIPS:**

1. Don't use your VPN. It will REALLY complicate the process - even if they're walking you through and manually opening closed doors.
2. Make sure the card you're using is good to go - accepts monthly recurring charges and works internationally.
3. If you get any messages from the support agent telling you something is
   prepared for you to try again - do so immediately. It's 100% time-sensitive.

--

That's it. That's the only way to solve it. I spent over a month doing it and while the agent was actually great the experience sucked.

Good luck and sorry it's so dependent on someone else. Cheers.